# Find closest value above current row that meets condition and apply function for each group

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I want to do a simple calculation for each row by group, but I need to refer to a previous row that meets certain conditions. I want to create a new variable, `results`. For each row in each group, I want to find the closest row above where `tag == "Y"` and `code` is not `NA`. Then, I want to use the `value` from that row, and multiply by the value in the current row.

**Minimal Example**

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("apples", "apples", "apples", "apples", 
                              "oranges", "oranges", "oranges", "oranges"), 
               id = 1:8, 
               tag = c("X", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "Y", "X", "X"), 
               code = c(1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA),
               value = c(1, 11, 4, 3, 9, 5, 7, 8)), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

     name id tag code value
1  apples  1   X    1     1
2  apples  2   Y    1    11
3  apples  3   Y   NA     4
4  apples  4   X    1     3
5 oranges  5   X   NA     9
6 oranges  6   Y    1     5
7 oranges  7   X   NA     7
8 oranges  8   X   NA     8
```

**Expected Output**

For example, for row 3, row 2 would be the closest that meets the conditions, so multiply 4 by 11 (to get 44). For row 4, row 3 does not meet the conditions, so we go to row 2, and multiply 3 by 11 (to get 33). And so on.

```
     name id tag code value results
1  apples  1   X    1     1      NA
2  apples  2   Y    1    11      NA
3  apples  3   Y   NA     4      44
4  apples  4   X    1     3      33
5 oranges  5   X   NA     9      NA
6 oranges  6   Y    1     5      NA
7 oranges  7   X   NA     7      35
8 oranges  8   X   NA     8      40
```

I am guessing that I will need to use `cumsum` and/or `fill`, but unsure how to use it here. I know that if I was preforming a calculation on the previous row, then I could use `lag`, but unsure how to search multiple values above. I am open to base R, `data.table`, `tidyverse`, or other solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(t = na_if(lag(value * (tag == 'Y' & !is.na(code))), 0)) %>%
  fill(t) %>%
  mutate(results = t * value)

# A tibble: 8 x 7
# Groups:   name [2]
  name       id tag    code value     t results
  <chr>   <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 apples      1 X         1     1    NA      NA
2 apples      2 Y         1    11    NA      NA
3 apples      3 Y        NA     4    11      44
4 apples      4 X         1     3    11      33
5 oranges     5 X        NA     9    NA      NA
6 oranges     6 Y         1     5    NA      NA
7 oranges     7 X        NA     7     5      35
8 oranges     8 X        NA     8     5      40
```

Answer (score 2):

with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[,result:=value*shift(nafill(fifelse(tag=='Y'&!is.na(code),value,NA),type = 'locf')), 
   by=name][]

      name    id    tag  code value result
    <char> <int> <char> <num> <num>  <num>
1:  apples     1      X     1     1     NA
2:  apples     2      Y     1    11     NA
3:  apples     3      Y    NA     4     44
4:  apples     4      X     1     3     33
5: oranges     5      X    NA     9     NA
6: oranges     6      Y     1     5     NA
7: oranges     7      X    NA     7     35
8: oranges     8      X    NA     8     40
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting the following error when I run it. `Error in fifelse(x.id < id, i.value * value, NA) : 
  'yes' is of type double but 'no' is of type logical. Please make sure that both arguments have the same type.`

Comment: works on my side with example dataset, but see my edit : forced `NA_REAl_`

Comment: That did it! But if I run it on a different iteration of the data.table (i.e., `df$code[3] <- 1`), then I don't get the correct output. For example, there's an `NA` for row 3, when it should be 44.

Comment: similar solution to @KU99 with data.table, could be ~10 times faster according to microbenchmark

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a second example data set to show the impact of changing the tags (making row 3 valid for multiplying):

```
df2 <- df
df2$code[3] <- 1
```

The aim is to filter the data.frame to valid rows to use in the calculating results, join back on the original data.frame, and use `fill` to propagate the last valid value. You add one to the id in the joined data.frame because that would the first ID for which the value would be valid to use. If id's are not sequential in the real data, you would need to add a dummy column with the row number.

For sake of showing impact of changing data, define the function:

```
computeResults <- function(data) {
  left_join(
      data,
      data %>% 
        filter(tag == "Y" & !is.na(code)) %>% 
        mutate(id = id + 1) %>% 
        select(name, id, prevVal = value),
      by = c("name", "id"),
      copy = TRUE
    ) %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    tidyr::fill(prevVal) %>% 
    mutate(results = value * prevVal) %>% 
    select(name, id, tag, code, value, results)
}
```

Original recipe

```
computeResults(df)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 6
#> # Groups:   name [2]
#>   name       id tag    code value results
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 apples      1 X         1     1      NA
#> 2 apples      2 Y         1    11      NA
#> 3 apples      3 Y        NA     4      44
#> 4 apples      4 X         1     3      33
#> 5 oranges     5 X        NA     9      NA
#> 6 oranges     6 Y         1     5      NA
#> 7 oranges     7 X        NA     7      35
#> 8 oranges     8 X        NA     8      40
```

Extra crispy/row 3 changed

```
computeResults(df2)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 6
#> # Groups:   name [2]
#>   name       id tag    code value results
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 apples      1 X         1     1      NA
#> 2 apples      2 Y         1    11      NA
#> 3 apples      3 Y         1     4      44
#> 4 apples      4 X         1     3      12
#> 5 oranges     5 X        NA     9      NA
#> 6 oranges     6 Y         1     5      NA
#> 7 oranges     7 X        NA     7      35
#> 8 oranges     8 X        NA     8      40
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess a base R approach could be:

```
df1<-df
df1$results<-NA

logi<-df1$tag=="Y" & is.na(df1$code)==FALSE

for (i in 1:length(logi)){
  
  if(i == 1 & logi[i] == FALSE){
    }else{
      
      if(logi[i] == FALSE & logi[i-1]==TRUE & logi[i+1]==FALSE){
        
        df1$results[i]<-df1$value[i]*df1$value[i-1]
        
        df1$results[i+1]<-df1$value[i+1]*df1$value[i-1]
      }
    }
  }


> df1
     name id tag code value results
1  apples  1   X    1     1      NA
2  apples  2   Y    1    11      NA
3  apples  3   Y   NA     4      44
4  apples  4   X    1     3      33
5 oranges  5   X   NA     9      NA
6 oranges  6   Y    1     5      NA
7 oranges  7   X   NA     7      35
8 oranges  8   X   NA     8      40
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for the example. However, if I run it on a different iteration of the dataframe (i.e., `df1$code[3] <- 1`), then I don't get the correct output. With that one, there's no value returned for row 3.

Comment: did you update the logi object after change df1$code[3]<- 1? should work as well.

Comment: Yes, I did. I think the issue is in the 2nd `if` statement, where `logi[i] == FALSE`. Essentially, if there are 2 `Y` tags next to one another that also have valid codes (i.e., not `NA`), then it would not calculate for a row with `Y`, since `logi` would be `TRUE` for that row.